# Ruby on Rails configure faraday http client correctly for SSL connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I am constantly getting `Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for nil port 80) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)` while using the ruby faraday gem.  I don't have alot of experience with ruby on rails.

I have a docker ruby on rails service running on elastic beanstalk that is using puma with ssl. `CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]`  I have a network load balancer configured with it to forward `443 -> 8443` (i've experimented with both self signed certs and real wild card certs).

```
ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', '8443', {
  key: '/var/app/ssl/something.key',
  cert: '/var/app/ssl/something.crt'
}
```

This configuration works as expected

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: staging
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
* Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:8443?cert=/var/app/ssl/something.crt&key=/var/app/ssl/something.key&verify_mode=none
```

and I can get the `healthz` status page with both types of certs.  Using `httpie` and `--verify=no` for the self signed.

```
$ http https://backend.something.com/healthz
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "name": "my-backend-service",
    "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

I have another ruby on rails backend service that makes api requests to this service using faraday.  Ive removed some of the `request/response` code from my actual.

```
def connection(baseUrl, options = {})
    conn = Faraday.new(url: baseUrl) do |c|

  # dont really know if this is needed or not
  # http.use_ssl? is always false
  c.adapter :net_http do |http|
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # if http.use_ssl?
  end
end
```

I don't know if this `http.verify_mode` is actually working.  I cant really find that method anywhere around here [on ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-use_ssl-3D)

If you try to make a request it will just end up faiing.

```
conn = connection(https://backend.something.com)
response = conn.post '/foo', params[:foo].to_json
```

The logs show from starting to parameters and then the `http.rb:939` error. I realize the parameters aren't valid here but they aren't my problem.

```
Started POST "/foo"
Processing by FooController#create as */*
Parameters: {"paramter"=>"something", "paramter"=>"something", "paramter"=>"something"}

ERROR -- : /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for nil port 80) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

If I make the same request from httpie or curl to this service I get the expected results over both `http/https`.

```
$ http POST https://backend.something.com parameter="something" parameter="something" parameter="something"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

If you inspect the `conn` object it kinda still seems like it is sitting on its default value for `@url_prefix = http:/`.  Found in the docs above, but I don't know if I'm looking at the correct thing the correct ruby way.  I imagined that `Faraday.new(url: baseUrl)` would parse the correct schema, which is `https`.

```
#<Faraday::Connection:0x0000565351701430 @parallel_manager=nil, @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.15.4"}, @params={}, @options=#<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)>, @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)>, @default_parallel_manager=nil, @builder=#<Faraday::RackBuilder:0x0000565351700f58 @handlers=[FaradayMiddleware::EncodeJson, FaradayMiddleware::ParseJson, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp]>, @url_prefix=#<URI::HTTP http:/>, @manual_proxy=false, @proxy=nil, @temp_proxy=nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the the address you are trying to connect to is invalid. From what I can see in the error:

```
ERROR -- : /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for nil port 80) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

it is nil. Ensure that the host is properly set.